# Single file non-validating xml parser/reader

Tags: c++, c, xml

I'm looking for a simple non-validating XML parser in either C or C++.

Several years back I found one that was just a single file solution but I can't find
it anymore.

I'm after some links and suggested ones that are very small and lightweight
ideally suited for an embedded platform.

Comment: Why would you use XML on an embedded platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like [pugixml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/). From their site...

> pugixml is a light-weight C++ XML
>   processing library. It features:
>
> - DOM-like interface with rich traversal/modification capabilities
> - Extremely fast non-validating XML parser which constructs the DOM
>     tree from an XML file/buffer
> - XPath 1.0 implementation for complex data-driven tree queries
> - Full Unicode support with Unicode interface variants and
>     automatic encoding conversions
>
> The library is extremely portable and
>   easy to integrate and use.
>
> pugixml is developed and maintained
>   since 2006 and has many users. All
>   code is distributed under the MIT
>   license, making it completely free to
>   use in both open-source and
>   proprietary applications.

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042855/boost-and-xml-c/1448859#1448859) has more info.

There is also [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) and [RapidXml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I went with tinyxml in the end.

Answer (score 2):

[Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/)

You can work with or without validation and in "streaming mode". It is very lightweight.

Comment: I'm not sure about the memory footprint, but the code size is a good 150k (on x86), which isn't what I'd call lightweight... For memory, the big question would be whether it allocates tons of tiny chunks for each string and each DOM object (which would lead to heavy overhead and possibly memory fragmentation), or whether it keeps lots of data together in larger allocations. Ideally a lightweight XML parser would modify the input string in-place, inserting null terminators where needed, and use that for the output.

Comment: Thanks, but it's too big for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a pure C, tiny xml parser available. It was cited in an earlier answer on SO, but I can't find it right now. If I remember right, it's just a few hundred lines of code.

**Update:** Here's the question/answer that references it:

[Is there a good tiny XML parser for an embedded C project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739474/is-there-a-good-tiny-xml-parser-for-an-embedded-c-project)

And the actual code:

http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/cstuff/file/tip/tinyxml

Comment: Thanks, I actually went with another parser called tinyxml which is different from this one.

Answer (score 0):

[RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) is a single-header (multiple headers if you want extra functionality) ultra-lightweight, ultra-fast implementation. It can operate in "destructive" mode, that means by setting pointers right into the XML and possibly overwriting some, avoiding all extra memory allocations and data copies.

[tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/) is not precisely single-header, but it is still fairly lightweight compared to other parsers. I've used it for half a decade without ever encountering an issue. The author has recently started with "tinyxml-2", which is supposedly better and even more lightweight, but I've not had occasion to actually try that one yet.

Answer (score -2):

http://mercurial.intuxication.org/hg/cstuff/file/tip/tinyxml

can this parser work with nested XML like

```
<CServiceType>
   <serno>61</serno>
   <caption1 />
   <caption2>Satelite</caption2>
   <caption3 />
</CServiceType>
```