# What are the major methods / libraries available for parsing XML?

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm performing a trade study evaluating various methods for parsing XML for a large system. I'm looking at both analytical and actual relative performance (space & time) on multiple platforms (iOS, Linux, OS X, Windows). My current candidate evaluation list of methods and libraries is the following:

- SAX

  - [NSXMLParser (iOS)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- Document Object Model

  - [System.Xml.XmlDocument (.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
- Pull Parsing

  - [System.Xml.XmlReader (.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx)
  - [XmlLite: A Small and Fast XML Parser for Native C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx)
- Data Binding

  - [Java API for XML Binding (JAXB)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)
  - [XML Schema Definition (XSD) Tool (.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx)
- XML as a Data Type

  - [Language Integrated Query (LINQ) to XML (.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx)
- [Virtual Token Descriptor (VTD)](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/)

Am I missing any particularly valuable tools, or different parsing methods?

Comment: You want XmlReader, not XmlTextReader.

Comment: Your JAXB link is for version 1, JAXB 2.2 (JSR-222) is the current release:  http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Linq-To-Xml/XDocument` which provides an alternative to `XmlDocument/DOM` .

Answer (score 2):

[Altova XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) provides an approach to build high-performance DTD or Schema-specific XML readers and writers.

I have no experience with the product, but have built prototypes for similar tools, because I think the basic premise is extremely good.

EDIT: A comment requested a pointer to "how this is done".  Dunno how they do it (know how I did it :), but here's a link that talks about at the Altova site:
http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-code-generation.html

Comment: Ira, +1, but can you provide a link showing how this is done? I use XMLSpy, but didn't know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You should add **RapidXML** and these:

[Ultra-portable, small complex config file library in ANSI C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525160/ultra-portable-small-complex-config-file-library-in-ansi-c/5543805#5543805)