# C based XML parser

Tags: c, xml, embedded

What are the recommended XML parsers for parsing a TMX file(XML based tilemap) in C?

What are the pros and cons of each, as I would like to have an efficient one because it will be running on an embedded system.

Comment: What type of embedded system, a msp430@8MHz with 64kB flash or a ARM11 imx31@500MHz with Linux and 1GB flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used libxml on an embedded product a while back. It may be right for you.

Comment: I've used libxml2 for embedded systems before as well.  Works great!

Answer (score 1):

On a high-level I think you should be looking at an event based parser rather than a DOM based one. DOM based parsers will take up a lot of memory building the XML tree.

Here's a from a similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131701/c-xml-library-for-embedded-systems). The top suggestion from that case looks to be one of the earliest xml parsers: [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I have written [sxmlc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sxmlc/) as a lightweight, potentially embeddable XML parser in C. See [my answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680551/1098603) (also linked by @PPC-Coder).

You can use it as DOM or SAX (to save memory), to parse either files or memory buffers.

Comment: A word of caution, repeatedly promoting your own project may get you flagged for excessive self-promotion - especially since these "recommend a library" questions are explicitly off-topic.